# Bootstrap dropdown inside tabs is not visible

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, drop-down-menu, tabs

I have `tabs`, where I put a `dropdown` element inside. The problem is, the dropdown list is not visible. Open/close event is working, but I don't see the list. If i move the dropdown outside the tabs, it is working. What's going on ?

**JavaScript**

```js
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('.tabs-student a').click(function (e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        $(this).tab('show');
    });
});
```

**HTML**

```html
<ul class="nav nav-tabs tabs-s">
  <li class="active"><a href="#tab-activity">A</a></li>
  <li class=""><a href="#tab-sales">B</a></li>
</ul>
<div class="tab-content">
  <div class="tab-pane active" id="tab-activity">
      <div class="btn-group left">
          <button class="btn btn-small dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">test1
              <span class="caret caret-fix"></span>
           </button>
           <ul class="dropdown-menu class-list scrollable-menu center">
              <li><label id="1" class="link active">test1</label></li>
              <li><label id="2" class="link">test2</label></li>
           </ul>
       </div>
  </div>
  <div class="tab-pane" id="tab-sales">
     test
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

I had to change the `overflow` property in the `.tab-content` class from `hidden` to e.g. `visible` in that case

Answer (score 0):

It should work without overriding the `overflow` property of `.tab content`.  The only other thing I noticed is that you're initializing tabs for the class `tabs-student`, but that class doesn't exist in your markup.  I think that's probably what you intended in the `ul` element with `.tabs-s`.  When I changed that, everything works just fine.

## [See this jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/KyleMit/aAqsX/)

This **JavaScript**:

```js
$('.tabs-student a').click(function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    $(this).tab('show');
});
```

Should correspond to this **HTML**:

```html
<ul class="nav nav-tabs tabs-student">
  <li class="active"><a href="#tab-activity">Activity</a></li>
  <li class=""><a href="#tab-sales">Sales</a></li>
</ul>
```

Should look like this:

[image: demo]